# Upgrade to Truffle 3.0, compile error

Tags: solidity, truffle, bug

I installed truffle V3.1.1 and whether I try truffle init or truffle init webpack, I am unable to compile the example contracts.

```
sudo truffle compile
/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-compile/profiler.js:204
        dependency_path = source.resolve_dependency_path(import_path, dependency_path);
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve_dependency_path' of undefined
```

Comment: I am new to truffle and have the same problem. I didn't find a solution. Instead of using V3.1.1, I installed the beta version of truffle and that solved my problem. Still waiting for a proper solution for V3.1.1.

Comment: I have the same issue,how did you install the beta version?

Comment: npm install -g truffle@3.1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the github issue: https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle/issues/362
Seems it is fixed by installing Truffle version 3.1.9.

```
npm install -g truffle@3.1.9
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue even in v3.1.9? What's next?